# Sets with no Prime Number-Generating Subsets

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Are there arbitrarily large sets $S \subset \mathbb N$ such that the set $\{1\} \cup S$ has no subset that sums to a prime number?

Comment: Why $\{1\} \cup S$ rather than just $S$ ?

Comment: @TomCollinge: Because otherwise the set of even numbers greater than $2$ is a trivial example.

Comment: OK, it's basically equivalent to asking for an arbitrarily large set which has 1 as an element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this sequence the answer is yes: http://oeis.org/A052349. On [this page](http://www.primepuzzles.net/puzzles/puzz_084.htm) there is a proof due to Chris Nash that this sequence is infinite.